# How can I make a deep copy of an Abstract Syntax Tree in scala?

Tags: scala, abstract-syntax-tree

The ast is written using case classes and its heavily nested. After parsing ,I would like to have a deep copy of it, and manipulate the copies independently.

Comment: if it is immutable there is no need to make a deep copy

Comment: btw, it is not clear what you are asking about. Is the AST written by yourself or from a lib?

Comment: @sschaef I had cases where I had to copy, because there were comparisons with `eq`.

Comment: @sschaef, its written by myself and indeed I need a deep copy

Comment: In that case the most reasonable way is just to add a method which makes a deep copy recursively.

Comment: I agree with sschaef, I would need a strong argument to need a copy of this. Otherwise, the use of case-classes may be the wrong way to go in the first place. Why wouldn't you want two structurally equivalent trees to be equal to each other? Maybe what you want is to override the equality method even?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @AlexeyRomanov said, you can write a recursive copy function yourself.

A small example:

```
trait A
case class B(a0: A, a1: A) extends A
case class C(value: Int) extends A

def copy(a: A): A = a match {
  case B(a0, a1) => B(copy(a0), copy(a1))
  case C(value) => C(value)
}

val a = B(C(0), B(C(1), C(2)))
val aCopy = copy(a)

a == aCopy //true
a eq aCopy //false
```